# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to change wlServerHost value in wlclient.properties

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have developed a mobile application using IBM Worklight v6 with the Android environment.

After generating the .apk file, I have tried to access the app with my android 4.0 device. I didn't get the expected outcome - the app failed to load.

Looking the error log which displayed on mobile, I now understand that I need to change `wlServerHost` value in my wlclient.properties.

By default, wlServerHost is set to my localhost ip address.
How to change this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831487/mobilefirst-7-1-osx-eclipse-server-url-setting Please reply at this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Worklight Studio, right click on your app, click on `Run As--> Build for Remote server` and provide the IP address and context root of your Worklight server. 
This will take care of making the appropriate changes to wlclient.properties.

Comment: thanks. It works. Additionally need to change the Contextroot also. By default it will be /worklight. Instead of this, gave my projectname as contextroot(</Projectname>).