# MobileFirst 7.1 OSX Eclipse server url setting

Tags: eclipse, macos, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I am using Eclipse Juno with MFP 7.1 in a Mac.

I put my server address in Configure Build and Deploy Target *http://example.com:80* and then use *Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server*.

In Windows, this updates my worklight.plist and wlclient.properties files with the new values for the server URL and port number, however in Mac the values remains *MyMacBookPro.local* as the server URL and the port number as *10080*.

Migrated to Eclipse Mars but the problem remains the same:
[image: MobileFirst Host Update]

[image]

Comment: Do not use Eclipse Juno with MFPF 7.1. Try again with Eclipse Kepler, Luna or Mars.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me using Eclipse Mars.2 and IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160419-1518, on Mac.

1. Created a new "test" project with "test" application and added the iPhone environment.
2. Selected Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server

   This shows "mbp-idan.local"
3. Selected Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target, and changed the values as follows:

   [image]
4. Selected Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server
5. Opened test\iphone\native\worklight.plist and I see the following:

   `<dict>
     <key>protocol</key> 
     <string>http</string>
     <key>host</key>
     <string>example.com</string>
     <key>port</key>
     <string>80</string>
     <key>wlServerContext</key>
     <string>/helloworld/</string>`

Comment: I have updated the question. Migrating to Mars does not even help? Any suggestions why is it happening. Seems like a problem with the MFP plugin installed. Can you recommend the download link of the plugin you are using for MFP 7.1.0

Comment: Either check for updates from the Eclipse marketplace, or if you are an IBM customer visit IBM Fix Central and download the latest available iFix.