# Mobile First 7.1 Adapter Request From Device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to build a hybrid application to my device.

In simulator I can call my adapter succesfully, but my device call adapter to my computer domain name which is wrong since I dont register any domain.

I want to call this via IP Address, how can it be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, find the worklight.plist file and change the `host` property to the correct IP address of the machine hosting the MobileFirst Server.

You can also adjust this in MobileFirst Studio by selecting `Run As -> Build Settings and Remote Target`, and re-building the application. The values you place there will find their way to the generated Xcode project's worklight.plist file.

Comment: I just created to my new server pointed to my machine IP Address. But somehow the application still requesting to <comp-name>.local:<port>
even though the port has changed from 10080 to 9080 like I stated for the new server..

Comment: same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831487/mobilefirst-7-1-osx-eclipse-server-url-setting